# Python. Variable in regular expression to find continuous (repeated) sequences of same string

Tags: python, regex, format, sequence, python-re

I need find a repeated sequences of same `my_string = 'ABCD'` in string `my_data = 'ABCDABCDRRRABCD'` and return the longest one `'ABCDABCD'`. 
If I use `result = ([max(i) for i in re.findall(r'((ABCD)\2+)', data)])` It's works fine, but I can't put a variable `my_string` so I can use it for difference strings in some loop.

Answer (score -1):

To put variable inside of regular expression you can use `.format`

```
result = ([max(i) for i in re.findall(r'(({0})\2+)'.format(my_string), my_data)])
```

Comment: typo? should be ```result = ([max(i) for i in re.findall(r'(({})\2+)'.format(my_string), my_data)])```

Comment: different type of placeholder, both style works fine

Comment: I did not know that :)